# SuperMicro x8sie-ln4f motherboard not using full memory

Tags: memory, motherboard, windows-server-2008-r2, supermicro

So I have a server board (SuperMicro X8SIE-LN4F), and the BIOS only sees 4GB of the RAM... I have 2x 4GB Sticks, slotted in the 2 blue colored slots...

When I boot into Windows, it shows 8.00 GB installed, 4.00 Usable...

Any idea what's happening?

Windows Server 2008 R2...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If its a 32 bit os, the limit it can access without PAE enabled is 4gb. You either need to switch to a 64 bit os, or look at how to enable PAE.

another thing i'd try is having them in banks that are next to each other - IE the first blue bank and the one next to it

Comment: tag description for Windows Server 2008 R2 says "R2 is available only in 64-bit editions"...

Comment: that seems slightly bizzare then. the system itself seems to support up to 32, and the ram is detected, just not usable...

Comment: perhaps BIOS settings need to be changed? The memory hole ( or something like that - can't recall) ?

Comment: hmm, try popping them in banks 1 and 2 ?

Comment: might want to edit and add that in your answer :P I'm not the OP :P

Comment: done ;p. I should not post with a headache ;p

Comment: Yes, I have an ProLiant server which has a SuperMicro motherboard, and I can remember there being some confusion over the slots, as you need to use one of each colour to get the same dual channel, IIRC.

Comment: @Sathya - Thanks for the correction with the Tags... New here, sorry...

I figured it out, I had to reseat the ram sticks quite a few times, and the AMIBios has practically nothing that's meaningful, save for an option that allows for PCI mem sharing, which takes about 256 megs if I enable it... 

I still don't know what I did, but now the Bios can detect all the 8 gigs... Earlier, Bios would only see 4, but windows would detect 8, and say 4 was usable...

Comment: @Abhishek good to hear, do click on the checkmark to indicate that this answer solved the problem, else you might want to put an answer of your own

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to know whether your modules are registered or unbuffered and their rank. Then make sure you follow the board's [memory configuration guidelines](http://www.supermicro.com/products/Memory/3400_support.cfm?pname=MBD-X8SIE-LN4F&DIMM=6). Depending of the type of modules you have, they may be unsupported or you may need to change the slot/channel configuration.

Comment: The modules are Registered ECC modules, quad rank... According to the board's recommendations, they need to be sitting in the blue slots (to put it mildly) They already are... :-(